# Is there a single word for "those and only those"?

Tags: word-choice

Example:

> **Those and only those** templates picked in the dialog need to become an effective workspace selection.

Is there a quality (an adjective?) to "templates" (in the example above) that conveys the same meaning as **those and only those**?

Comment: But who knows what "an effective workspace selection" might mean? How can something that has been picked *become* a selection? It already is a selection. Also the phrase "need to become" is very vague. Does someone have to take some action to cause this to happen? Or are they like tadpoles who must fulfill their destiny?

Answer (score 1):

> "Only those templates"

Or

> "Those templates only"

Would convey that meaning fine and concisely enough.

Comment: I agree with this, but I think it's still not quite the same as "those and only those".  It's like double-underlining a statement -- *mostly*, but not *entirely*, superfluous.

Comment: If OP wants to maximise that emphasis, then they will have to use "those and only those".